# add to JSON ($payload={}) on condition

Tags: json, perl, nagios

I feed JSON to some webhook to trigger a notification (M$ Teams). This works well. However, I want to extend my Perl script: I need to **add a new node to my "messagecard" construct on a certain condition**.

E.g. I defined this:

```
my $payload={};
$payload = {
    '@type' => 'MessageCard',
    '@context' => 'http://schema.org/extensions',
    themeColor => $event{COLOR},
    text => $event{SERVICEOUTPUT},
    sections => [{
        facts => [{
            name => 'Type',
            value => "$event{NOTIFICATIONTYPE} $event{ADDITIONALINFO}"
        },
        ]
    }],
    potentialAction => [{
        '@type' => "OpenUri",
        name => "View Monitoring",
        targets => [{
            os => "default",
            uri => $naemon_url
        }]
    }]
};

$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $req = POST($opt_webhook
    , 'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    , 'Content' => encode_json($payload)
);
my $resp = $ua->request($req);
```

And if (conditon), I want to extend this as follows (order is important):

```
$payload = {
    '@type' => 'MessageCard',
    '@context' => 'http://schema.org/extensions',
    themeColor => $event{COLOR},
    text => $event{SERVICEOUTPUT},
    sections => [{
        facts => [{
            name => 'Type',
            value => "$event{NOTIFICATIONTYPE} $event{ADDITIONALINFO}"
        },
        ]
    }],
    potentialAction => [{
        '@type' => "OpenUri",
        name => "View Monitoring",
        targets => [{
            os => "default",
            uri => $naemon_url
        }]
    },
    {
        '@type' => "OpenUri",
        name => "Notes (Logs, Docs,..)",
        targets => [{
            os => "default",
            uri => $event{SERVICENOTESURL}
        }]
  }]
};
```

I am unsure how this can be achieved. Can anyone please provide wisdom how to tackle this?

Comment: Do you have `use strict` and `use warnings` turned on? Your `$ua` isn't declared.

Comment: @simbabque yes, this is just an excerpt of the current code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can push into the array reference that you've got inside your `potentialAction` key. In order to do that, you need to *dereference* it as an array.

```perl
my $payload = {
    '@type' => 'MessageCard',
    potentialAction => [{
        name => "View Monitoring",
        targets => [{
            os => "default",
        }]
    }]
};

if ($maybe) {
    push @{ $payload->{potentialAction} }, {
        name => "Notes (Logs, Docs,..)",
        targets => [{
            os => "default",
        }]
    };
}
```

If your Perl version is 5.24 or newer you can also use [postfix dereferencing](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2016/04/postfix-dereferencing-is-stable-is-v5-24/%5C), which some people find easier to read.

```perl
push $payload->{potentialAction}->@*, ...
```

See [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref) and [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut) for more information.